In Flutter fl_chart, how to add horizontal tooltip as below?
In flutter, fl_chart(0.59.0), the vertical tooltip can be added easily, "2024-08-26" as displayed in the below pic. but the horizontal tooltip("3.74%" in the below pic) seems difficult to draw for me. Could anyone provide some advices? Thanks very much.

LineChart(
  LineChartData(
     lineTouchData: LineTouchData(
        handleBuiltInTouches: true,
        getTouchedSpotIndicator: (barData, spotIndexes) => spotIndexes
            .map(
              (e) => TouchedSpotIndicatorData(
                  const FlLine(
                      color: Colors.red, strokeWidth: 1.5, dashArray: [2, 2]),
                  FlDotData(
                    getDotPainter: (p0, p1, p2, p3) => FlDotCirclePainter(
                        radius: 3.5,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        strokeWidth: 2.0,
                        strokeColor: Colors.red),
                  )),
            ).toList(),
        touchTooltipData: LineTouchTooltipData(
          showOnTopOfTheChartBoxArea: true,
          fitInsideHorizontally: true,
          fitInsideVertically: true,
          tooltipRoundedRadius: 1.5,
          tooltipPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 1.0),
          getTooltipColor: (touchedSpot) => Colors.red,
          tooltipMargin: 0.0,
          getTooltipItems: (touchedSpots) => touchedSpots
              .map(
                (e) => LineTooltipItem(
                    widget.data.xSeries == null
                        ? ''
                        : widget.data.xSeries![e.spotIndex],
                    const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 10.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              ).toList(),
          ),
          getTouchLineEnd: (barData, spotIndex) => double.infinity,
     ),
  )
);


can you share the code?

@MunsifAli Thanks for the reply, the code has been added. The existing code has implement the vertical tooltip, I'm wandering if there is way to add the horizontal tooltip as the vertical one.
